# RadDatePicker perfoming PostBack even when not changing date

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I'm using Telerik ASP.NET Rad Ajax controls, version 2011.2.915.40.

I've added a RadDatePicker to my page, and initialize the date to today.

Upon clicking the raddatepicker, and selecting same date I'm on twice(first deselects it, seoncds selects it) - Postback occurs to the server. However, the `OnSelectedChange` function of the datepicker does not get called.

Optimally, the control won't postback if the date wasn't changed, but I can settle for a postback and calling the `OnSelectedChange` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After contacting Telerik with a support ticket,
I found out this issue was fixed in version 2012.2.607.

The `RadDatePicker` now postbacks only when the date was changed.